# having c-tor and d-tor gives segmentation fault while without them no segmentation fault

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
struct Tnode {
 Tnode *left;
 Tnode *right;
 int content;

 Tnode (int item = 0) {
    this->content = item;
    left = nullptr;
    right = nullptr;
}};


class KrTree {
private:
Tnode* root;

void printHelper (Tnode* root) {
    if(!root) {
        return;
    }
    printHelper(root->left);
    cout << root->content << " ";
    printHelper(root->right);
}

void addHelper (Tnode *root, int item) {
    if (root->content < item) {
        if (root->right) {
            addHelper(root->right, item);
        } else {
            root->right = new Tnode (item);
        }

    }else {
        if (root->left) {
            addHelper(root->left, item);
        } else {
            root->left = new Tnode (item);
        }
    }
}

public:
//    KrTree (){
//    }

void addTreeNode (int item) {
    if (root){
        this->addHelper(root, item);
    } else {
        root = new Tnode(item);
    }
}

void tnodes_count () {

}

void deleteTreeNode () {

}

void printTree () {
    printHelper (this->root);
}

//~KrTree (){}};
```

Above I've implented a binary search tree. please note i have commented my c-tor and d-tor. My problem is above code works good but give segmentation fault when i enable my c-tor and d-tor.

Here is client code:

```
KrTree* tree = new KrTree();
tree->printTree();
tree->addTreeNode(7);
tree->addTreeNode(2);
tree->addTreeNode(10);
tree->addTreeNode(1);
tree->addTreeNode(5);
tree->addTreeNode(9);
tree->addTreeNode(20);

tree->printTree();
```

I know that i am missing something very silly here. please let me know whey enabling my c-tor and d-tor gives segmentation fault

Comment: a minor typo //~KrTree (){}};

Comment: Works fine on [ideone](http://ideone.com/jkoXkV). Where specifically is the segmentation fault - what's it trying to write or dereference? What compiler etc are you using?

Comment: @Amaresh *having c-tor and d-tor gives segmentation fault while without them no segmentation fault* --  Of course if you don't have buggy functions called, you won't see an error.

Comment: A default constructed `KrTree` has an uninitialized `root` member (unless I've missed something).  I think what you're seeing is simply undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. D'oh, good spot. That's probably worth an answer. I can't see why his empty constructor would generate anything different than an omitted constructor, but could believe that's it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I got it. Adding **bold:root(nullptr) **will fixe the issue. There is something follow up which in my view is more interestingly subtle. in code above what is difference if i write **this->printHelper (root);** instead of **printHelper (this->root);** ??? thanks again

Comment: Hi @Rup, I'm using xcode (mac os) and inbuilt C++ compiler.

Comment: `this->printHelper (root)` vs `printHelper (this->root)` - these are the same, and the same as just `printHelper(root)`, provided you don't have anything else called `printHelper` or `root` defined in the scope you're working in that would override the values taken from the class. e.g. if you call this from inside the printHelper method itself then `root` would mean the method argument not the class value unless you wrote `this->root`.

Comment: @Rup Thank you! :) That helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without constructor KrTree.root is initialized by default 0 value. With constructor, well, it doesn't happen. Then addTreeNode tries to use this value as reference and segmentation fault happens. Default values in debug mode in Visual Studio are something like 0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd. You can debug application up to first addTreeNode and see actual value for root.
To fix this you should promptly initialize member variable value in constructor. For example:

```
KrTree () : root(nullptr) {
}
```

Comment: "Without constructor KrTree.root is initialized by default 0 value." - I'm not sure that's true. It may happen by accident, but members aren't guaranteed to be initialised the same way that static values are. I also don't see why the compiler wouldn't generate the same debug-init constructor by default if you didn't specify one at all.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment...

From the code shown a default constructed KrTree has an uninitialized root member. What you're seeing is simply undefined behaviour.